Bath Fan Roof Outlet Coupling
I have a bath fan venting out of a 3” pvc pipe through the roof. Looking for input on the best way to retrofit a bend at the top to prevent water getting in. I don’t want to spend $100 on one of the below options. Should I just glue a 90 and a 45 together? Not sure if there’s better options I’m not considering.



PVC mushroom vent cap. Under $15 for one that fits 3 or 4 inches from the more reasonable suppliers - 5 times that if you shop poorly for exactly the same thing from less savory vendors.

Image source, no endorsement implied.

thank you, I found one at the local supply house. Quick question: this won’t cause any negative backflow/pressure with the exhausted air hitting the crown?

Any - of course. So would two elbows. Enough to be a problem? Likely not, unless the vent is just barely functioning without it.
